# Display is progressively getting worse and is corrupting (?)

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display

This started happening around a week ago and has got progressively worse.

This happens only sometimes and has only happened three of four times. Although when it does happen each time the effect observed is greater.

A quick reboot has fixed the problem. However, I'm afraid that this is the symptom of a more serious issue.

What should I do to diagnose and fix this?

[image: The offending issue]

And the following happened after @Dan answered the above:

```
Anonymous UUID:       579FAA51-97AF-6A40-C494-84C64C21A37E

Mon Dec 16 07:52:23 2013
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff7f92e71fac): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 3 7f 0 0 0 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0xd2000000 0xffffff80b04c3000 0x0a5480a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/SourceCache/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.4.12/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff808ca9b6c0 : 0xffffff8010a22f69 
0xffffff808ca9b740 : 0xffffff7f92e71fac 
0xffffff808ca9b810 : 0xffffff7f915cd53d 
0xffffff808ca9b8d0 : 0xffffff7f91699d9e 
0xffffff808ca9b910 : 0xffffff7f91699dfc 
0xffffff808ca9b980 : 0xffffff7f9191e5be 
0xffffff808ca9bab0 : 0xffffff7f916bdd41 
0xffffff808ca9bad0 : 0xffffff7f915d408d 
0xffffff808ca9bb80 : 0xffffff7f915d1bae 
0xffffff808ca9bd80 : 0xffffff7f915d2c19 
0xffffff808ca9be60 : 0xffffff7f9157e1e2 
0xffffff808ca9beb0 : 0xffffff7f92e4466c 
0xffffff808ca9bf00 : 0xffffff7f92e4355e 
0xffffff808ca9bf20 : 0xffffff8010a4a15a 
0xffffff808ca9bfb0 : 0xffffff8010ad6aa7 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f9157c000->0xffffff7f917ebfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f90fe8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f9156c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f91529000
         com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.4.12)[A4934A66-0E30-36E9-984A-650481102449]@0xffffff7f92e64000->0xffffff7f92e76fff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.4.12)[661E3C87-5B97-3272-88FF-B9BA9B6E24ED]@0xffffff7f92e5c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[045D5D6F-AD1E-36DB-A249-A346E2B48E54]@0xffffff7f91437000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f90fe8000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f91529000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.0.4)[E04639C5-D734-3AB3-A682-FE66694C6653]@0xffffff7f92e5f000
         com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla(8.1.8)[3666E0FC-87C7-3329-BD8C-2F1ADED100A4]@0xffffff7f917f6000->0xffffff7f91aa2fff
            dependency: com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla(8.1.8)[0A1B6F41-168D-307A-BABD-162F3B3C2786]@0xffffff7f9157c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f90fe8000
         com.apple.driver.AGPM(100.14.11)[087FCB18-55FA-300E-9D22-DDE636C74BE1]@0xffffff7f92e42000->0xffffff7f92e53fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.8)[447B4896-16FF-3616-95A2-1C516B2A1498]@0xffffff7f90fe8000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily(5.5.1d27)[C86803C1-60BC-386D-9C54-2E6D74CCEA74]@0xffffff7f91ef3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.3.6)[86BA68C6-18DD-30A1-ABF6-54597AD6C277]@0xffffff7f9156c000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.3.6)[38E388A5-92D6-3388-B799-F2498E582287]@0xffffff7f91529000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.4.12)[C171C5AF-1BB6-385A-A4DB-3ED56267111E]@0xffffff7f92e3c000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
13A603

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 13.0.0: Thu Sep 19 22:22:27 PDT 2013; root:xnu-2422.1.72~6/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 1D9369E3-D0A5-31B6-8D16-BFFBBB390393
Kernel slide:     0x0000000010800000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8010a00000
System model name: MacBookPro6,2 (Mac-F22586C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 56624078220922
last loaded kext at 272165279196: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs 1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f92f74000, size 65536)
last unloaded kext at 368430739213: com.apple.filesystems.msdosfs   1.9 (addr 0xffffff7f92f74000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 3.2.6
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 3.2.6
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.5d0
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.14.11
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver    124
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver   2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC   1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.60
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.0d1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.0
com.apple.GeForceTesla  8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphics   8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHDGraphicsFB 8.1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.13
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.1.12
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.4d1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  240.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.3.5
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  325.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 240.2
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.6.0
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet    3.6.9b9
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331   700.20.22
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.9.9
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.9.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   650.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 216.0.0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   153
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   216.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.4.12
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.7
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.2.5
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.9.4fc11
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.14
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   91
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.5.2fc2
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.5.1d27
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDANV50HalTesla   8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.2.0f6
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.4.12
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.11d1
com.apple.nvidia.classic.NVDAResmanTesla    8.1.8
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.6d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 240.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   650.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  650.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.7
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCISerialATAPI   2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController 1.0.3b3
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b4
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   600.34
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.5.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 650.4.4
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.6.0
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 650.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  278.10
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  7
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 371.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  21
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.8
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro6,2, BootROM MBP61.0057.B0F, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.4 GHz, 4 GB, SMC 1.58f17
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics, Intel HD Graphics, Built-In, 288 MB
Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M, PCIe, 256 MB
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 2 GB, DDR3, 1067 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54313235533642465238432D47372020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x93), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22)
Bluetooth: Version 4.2.0f6 12982, 3 services, 15 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en1
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS545032B9SA02, 320.07 GB
Serial ATA Device: MATSHITADVD-R   UJ-898
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
USB Device: BRCM2070 Hub
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
USB Device: Hub
USB Device: Built-in iSight
USB Device: IR Receiver
Thunderbolt Bus:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This means your video card or motherboard is failing -- if your Mac is still under Apple Care warranty, you're set. If not, it'll cost you $$ to fix. Take it to an Apple store or Apple certified repair shop, as it's nothing you can fix yourself. Yes reboots will help temporarily but it will get progressively worse over time, in my experience. The good news is that your data is fine.

Comment: Same experience for me, getting worse over time. Up to a point where now my Macbook Pro doesn't even show the login screen (after 2 or 3 years starting to exhibit this behavior).  In my experience, things were also getting worse when the temperature get higher (during hot summer days or when running CPU/GPU heavy applications).